# Connect program in C written in WSL to MySQL database hosted in Windows?

Tags: mysql, c, wsl-2

I am using WSL to write a C program to do some simple operations in a MySQL Database installed on WINDOWS.

When I run the C file that tries to connect to the database I get the following error: Error connecting to database: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Comment: To connect to a different machine (i.e. the host machine of your WSL2 VM), you need to use TCP socket. You're trying to connect via a unix socket, which is local to the machine.